# Python [Graphviz pydot]

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

I'm trying to visualize a simple decision tree model :

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
import pandas as pd
iris=datasets.load_iris()
df=pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
y=iris.target
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree.fit(df,y)
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=dot_data,  
            filled=True, rounded=True,
            special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

I got this error: `TypeError: add_node()` received a non node class object: `<pydotplus.graphviz.Node object at 0x000000000927A160>`

Thanks for your help

Comment: It helps if you put in the whole stacktrace

Comment: Also, it works for me

Comment: As recommended by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), imports should better be placed at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me without any errors, using `pydot == 1.2.4` and `scikit-learn == 0.19.1` (which [replaced the package `sklearn`](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/)):

```
from IPython.display import Image  
import pandas as pd
import pydot
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

iris = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
y = iris.target
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree.fit(df, y)
dot_data = export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=None,
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True)
(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Also, there is no need to pass a `StringIO` object. As the docstring of the function `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz` [says](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2e85c8608c93ad0e3290414c4e5e650b87d44b27/sklearn/tree/export.py#L156):

> dot_data : string
>
> String representation of the input tree in GraphViz dot format.
>     Only returned if `out_file` is None.

beware of the [default value](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2e85c8608c93ad0e3290414c4e5e650b87d44b27/sklearn/tree/export.py#L100) though:

> out_file : file object or string, optional (default='tree.dot')
>     Handle or name of the output file. If `None`, the result is
>     returned as a string. This will the default from version 0.20.